# Bluetooth Problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04

Whenever I connect a Bluetooth speaker or headset, the device remains connected as long as it is in use. However, if it is not in use even for a few minutes, the Bluetooth automatically turns off. And when I try to switch it on again, it won't. I need to restart my laptop and then only Bluetooth works again.

Is there any way by which I can stop Bluetooth from turning off by itself? Also, why won't it start again without needing to restart the laptop?

Answer (score 24):

See below for what worked for me. Bluetooth could not be toggled on or off from applet, nor from settings effectively. It just turned itself off for no reason. Reboot of OS would not work either. Here is someone else's fix and explanation that worked for me. PS Bluetooth applet image is still invisible.

- update bluez to >=5.28.2

  18.04 ships with a buggy bluez package for now; newer version is available from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bluetooth/+archive/ubuntu/bluez) :

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install bluez
  ```

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Funny that they give you a message that it's an unstable version when you enable the PPA... obviously the released version is unstable already!

Comment: I had rather intermittent, crackling bluetooth speaker connection which was solved by this fix

Comment: thanks, works for me in Ubuntu 18.04.2 (upgrade from 5.48 to 5.50 by ppa).

Comment: Did not work! Even updating, bluetooth does not turn on. I think the bluetooth card is disabled, it's gone! ;(

Comment: Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 17):

I restart it in the terminal, and it works:

Code:

```
$ sudo -i
# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power off
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (your bluetooth address)
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# trust
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# pair
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# unblock
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# power off
[bluetooth]# power on
```

Comment: bluetoothctl does not open! the bluetooth card burned?

Comment: what if it shows "No default controller available" after power off!

Answer (score 9):

My problem is similar, but it happens only after the computer wakes up from the suspend. It only happens to Bluetooth speaker; there is no such issue with Bluetooth mouse. The current solution I find is to reboot the Bluetooth service by`sudo service bluetooth restart`.

Comment: I keep having to restart all the time. @newbuntie's suggestion to upgrade the packages seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did not work! Even updating, bluetooth does not turn on. I think the bluetooth card is disabled, it's gone! ;(