# Bluetooth headphones connected but no sound, only speakers as an output option - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

This happens on an asus zenbook flip s ux370u.

I tried a few things but none worked, plus most of solutions are for previous versions of ubuntu which used different bluetooth services.

So i tried to install more recent version of bluez from ppa found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040497/bluetooth-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

but nothing changed on that, i still can't find the headphones and an output option in sound settings even though they're connected.
Here what i can see from terminal:

```
    Device 00:00:00:00:41:1F Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:41:1F Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:41:1F Class: 0x00240404
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:41:1F Icon: audio-card
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:41:1F Connected: yes
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same problem that I have occasionally.

The fix for me is using pylover's a2dp.py from github:
https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae

Launch it from a shell, might be required to run several times, clearing/redoing the related Bluetooth paring before - allowing some time for the pairing to succeed.

As always; keep track of Bluetooth being on, and whether the paired device is the one receiving sound output - as per "sound settings".

Answer (score 0):

Got the easiest and right solution in the ubuntu italian forum.
All i needed was:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

then i unpaired the device, reboot , paired it again and everything now worked. I can now see the headphones as sound output in sound settings.
Hope it helps!

Thanks!